# Sorting an array of objects by a number in each object

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
var points = [{num:40, label:"category1"}, {num:100, label:"category2"}, {num:1, label:"category3"}, {num:5, label:"category4"}, {num:25, label:"category5"}, {num:10, label:"category6"}];
```

I want to create a function that creates a new array of these objects sorted by the num property in points (descending)

So the new array will look like this:

```
var newpoints =[{num:100, label:"category2"}, {num:40, label:"category1"}, {num:25, label:"category5"}, {num:10, label:"category6"}, {num:5, label:"category4"}, {num:1, label:"category3"}];
```

I think I can call .sort() on points and pass an anonymous function which returns an array of its numbers descending:

```
var newpoints = points.sort(function(a.num,b.num){return b.num-a.num});
```

...but how do I also keep the associated key/property values of label in there too?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wpfmonsc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : just need to parse string to number using `parseInt()`

```
$(function(){
var points = [{num:40, label:"category1"}, {num:100, label:"category2"}, {num:1, label:"category3"}, {num:5, label:"category4"}, {num:25, label:"category5"}, {num:10, label:"category6"}];
   //alert(JSON.stringify( points ));
    var newpoints = points.sort(function(a, b){    if(parseInt(a.num) > parseInt(b.num)) return 1;else if(parseInt(a.num) < parseInt(b.num)) return -1;else return 0});
   // alert(JSON.stringify( newpoints ));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/h88e1re1/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the ordering function passed into the sort function, are two objects from the array. You passed in a.num and b.num which seems to me like you have misunderstood what is passed in. The arguments passed in are two elements from the array (each being an object with a label- and a num-property). You should name them a and b, so that querying their property num by a.num and b.num is correct. Inside the ordering function you can use the num-property as the basis for comparison like this:

```
var points = [{num:40, label:"category1"}, {num:100, label:"category2"}, {num:1,   label:"category3"}, {num:5, label:"category4"}, {num:25, label:"category5"}, {num:10, label:"category6"}];

points.sort(function(a,b){return b.num - a.num}); // Sorts the array in place
```

The labels will stay intact - each object will have the same label as before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also you a readymade functions from various libraries.. I personally prefer $linq : http://jscriptlinq.codeplex.com/

A simple sort based on a property can be implemented as

```
var arr = [{id: 'a', pos: 5},
    {id: 'd', pos: 2},
    {id: 'b', pos: 4},
    {id: 'c', pos: 3},
    {id: 'e', pos: 1}];

// col1 = ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
var col1 = $linq(arr)
    .orderBy(function (x) { return x.pos; })
    .select(function (x) { return x.id; })
    .toArray();

// col2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
var col2 = $linq(arr)
    .orderBy("x => x.id")
    .select("x => x.id")
    .toArray();
```